# Mac OSX 10.6 leaves open files on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac-osx, server-message-block

We've got several Mac OS X 10.6 clients who connect to our Windows 2000 & 2003 File Servers - No Active Dir, just file shares.

I'm finding that **the Mac clients keep lots of connections open on our server, even when they have no files open**.  My tests show that just browsing the folders using Finder keeps all of the folders open.  Windows "Computer Management" shows these sessions with 15-20 open files, and these are causing us to reach our connection limit and locking down the server.

I've disabled the creation of DS_Store, thinking that was the problem, but it was not.
Also, tried disabling named streams - no luck.

I ran a test - 
A Mac client browsed to a folder called "AFolder" with one file called "Program.doc", then navigated to another folder, and recorded the activity with ProcMon on the server (W2K):

http://www.thelifechurch.com/pete/10.6.jpg

From computer manager, you can see that the folder “D:\Shared\AFolder” is still open, and thus dozens of folders stay open when they browse around (even after closing finder):

http://www.thelifechurch.com/pete/cm.jpg

I tested the same thing with **Mac OS X 10.5.7 and it did not have that problem**. Here is the ProcMon results:

http://www.thelifechurch.com/pete/10.5.jpg

I'm not too familiar with these file operations, can anyone tell whats causing this?

The best I can tell by comparing the 10.5 and 10.6 logs, is that 10.6 does a 
`CreateFile D:\Shared\AFolder`, 
and then never closes it, even after I navigate out to a different folder.  Whereas, 10.5 does close the folder.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing similar issue...

Comment: No, we decided to move to a linux file-server.  Trying clearos right now

Comment: I seriously surprised this issue isn't getting more attention, I guess the problem is going by different names, I thought it was a permissions issue for so long.

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as Spotlight (the MacOS Search mechanism) is indexing those files once the shares are mounted.  I believe that there is a preference to turn off the indexing of network shares.

I don't have facilities to test right now, but you could try:

- Try running `mdutil -i off
  /path/to/volume` to turn off indexing
  for the relevant volume.  If that
  works you could set it up as a script
  to run at startup or login.
- You could also try creating an empty
  file called ".metadata_never_index"
  and placing that at the root of the
  network mount point.  It should
  prevent spotlight from indexing the
  folder and subfolders (at least under
  that mountpoint.)

Comment: Thanks, I just tried both suggestions, rebooted, but the open connections still keep accumulating.  So it doesn't seem to be spotlight.

Comment: @Pete Shack - Sorry, then.  I've got nothing else for you...

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. Lots of opened files o windows server.

The problem was - AVAST antivirus on MacOS. Uninstalling it fixed the problem.